# AFNetworking Error when having multiple requests

Tags: objective-c, swift, afnetworking-2

It seems that sometimes when I call certain methods that contain GET requests using the AFHTTPRequestOperation Manager, it sometimes improperly calls back to another succeed block/closure from another GET request using the Operation Manager.

According to the error logs, it seems like it has to do with unwrapped optionals within the closure, which seems to an issue discussed here concerning Swift and Objective C compatability, but I'm not sure how to necessarily fix the issue with my particular set of code.

I also don't want to use the Alamo Fire Swift Library, I'd rather stick to the AFNetworking Cocoapod, as the writer of the library said that both should be usable within a Swift project.

Here is the error log I get.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN at 0x0000000100147e48

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Kickit                         0x0000000100147e48 Kickit.GroupsDataSource.(logoutForce (Kickit.GroupsDataSource) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (GroupsDataSource.swift:809)
1  Kickit                         0x00000001001474dc Kickit.GroupsDataSource.(logoutForce (Kickit.GroupsDataSource) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (GroupsDataSource.swift:823)
2  Kickit                         0x0000000100143074 reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>, @owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in (Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>, Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>)) -> (@out ()) with unmangled suffix "_constprop0" (GroupsDataSource.swift:365)
3  Kickit                         0x0000000100193934 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in (Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>, Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>)) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned (@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>, @owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> (@unowned ()) (AppDelegate.swift:615)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001970253ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019702536c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000197029980 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 932
7  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186241fa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018624004c __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
9  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018616d0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
10 GraphicsServices               0x000000018f30f5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
11 UIKit                          0x000000018aaa23c0 UIApplicationMain + 1488
12 Kickit                         0x0000000100193ca4 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019704ea08 start + 4
```

The success block here is AppDelegate: 615

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

                var user_id : Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("user_id") as Int

                if (justSeenEventIDs.count > 0){
                    manager.GET(serverURL+"users/seen_events.json",
                        parameters: ["user_id" : userID()!, "event_ids" : justSeenEventIDs],
                        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in

                            println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
                            if (responseObject.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){


                            }


                        },
                        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription + " code: " + "\(error.code)")
                    })
                }
```

The beginning of the success block in this function is GroupsDataSource: 365

```
func loadGroups(completion:(dictionary : NSDictionary?) -> Void){

        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

        manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer() as AFJSONRequestSerializer

        manager.GET(serverURL+"users/get_state.json",
            parameters: ["user_id" : userID()!],
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in

                println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
                if (responseObject.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){

                    var dict : NSDictionary = responseObject as NSDictionary

                    if (dict.objectForKey("groups") != nil){
                        self.parseDataFromStateDictionary(responseObject as NSDictionary)

//                        self.parseDataFromGroupsDictionary(responseObject as NSDictionary)
                    }
                    else{
                        completion(dictionary: responseObject as? NSDictionary)
                    }




                }else if(responseObject.isKindOfClass(NSArray)){


                }

                completion(dictionary: nil)
            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) -> Void in


                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription + " code: " + "\(error.code)")
                completion(dictionary: nil)
        })
    }
```

And the last closure: GroupsDataSource: 809. The reason why you see a lot of CLSNSLogv is because this error seems only to happen in In-House Distribution (production) as opposed to just building straight to device through the lightning cable. If this helps, only CLSNSLogv 4, 5, and 6 are called, but not 3.

```
func logoutForce(){

        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("user_id") != nil){

            var user_id : Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("user_id") as Int

            CLSNSLogv("logoutForce 3", getVaList([]))
            manager.GET(serverURL+"users/logout.json",
                parameters: ["user_id" : user_id],
                success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in

                    CLSNSLogv("logoutForce 4", getVaList([]))
                    println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
                    if (responseObject.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){

                        CLSNSLogv("logoutForce 5", getVaList([]))
                        var obj : NSDictionary = responseObject as NSDictionary
                        if (obj.objectForKey("no_user_with_auth") != nil){
                            return
                        }

                        CLSNSLogv("logoutForce 6", getVaList([]))
                        NSLog("Here is the dictionary from logging out \(obj.description)")
                        var created : Bool = obj.objectForKey("isLoggedOut") as Bool
                        if (created){
                            CLSNSLogv("logoutForce 7", getVaList([]))
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("phone_number")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("name")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("user_id")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("auth_token")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("photo_url")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("photo_updated")
                            GroupsDataSource.sharedInstance.selectedGroup = nil
                            GroupsDataSource.sharedInstance.groupsArray = Array()
                            GroupsDataSource.sharedInstance.groupDictionary = Dictionary()
                            GroupsDataSource.sharedInstance.eventDictionary = Dictionary()
                            GroupsDataSource.sharedInstance.starredEventsArray = Array()
                            logout = false
                            CLSNSLogv("logoutForce 8", getVaList([]))
                        }


                    }else if(responseObject.isKindOfClass(NSArray)){

                    }
                },
                failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    CLSNSLogv("logoutForce 9", getVaList([]))
                    println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            })
        }
        CLSNSLogv("logoutForce 10", getVaList([]))
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("phone_number")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("name")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("user_id")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("auth_token")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("photo_url")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("photo_updated")
        GroupsDataSource.sharedInstance.selectedGroup = nil
        GroupsDataSource.sharedInstance.groupsArray = Array()
        GroupsDataSource.sharedInstance.starredEventsArray = Array()
        logout = false
        CLSNSLogv("logoutForce 11", getVaList([]))                        

    }
```

Comment: put -ObjC flag in other linker flag in project targert.Please try this may be it's helpful.Let us know ur comments.

Comment: Already there @RenishDadhaniya

Comment: I ended up using Alamofire instead and that ended up resolving my issue. Written by the creator of AFNetworking https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire